Area of 3D triangle projected onto a plane
I have the following question:
A triangle with vertices P=(2,2,4), Q=(3,4,3) and R=(1,3,2) are on the same side of the plane given by the equation 2x+y+z=2. Imagine light shining perpendicular to the plane, casting a shadow of triangle PQR onto the plane. What is the area of the shadow triangle?
If I know the normal to the plane is <2,1,1>. can I project the vector of each side of the triangle (PQ, PR, QR) along the normal of the vector to find the vertices of the shadow? I'm confused on the process for this problem.

Hi! Please typeset your mathematics using MathJax. Doing so will help keep your answer from being poorly received. Of course, MathJax has a learning curve, but if you make an honest initial attempt, experienced users will generally be happy to help you improve and fix whatever errors you experience. ¶ For instance, $2x+y+z = 2$ yields $2x+y+z = 2$, and $\langle 2, 1, 1 \rangle$ yields $\langle 2, 1, 1 \rangle$.

You rather want to use the fact that the projected area is
$$A_{\text{proj}}=A|\cos\alpha|=A\,|\mathbf{\hat n_t\cdot \hat n}|,$$
where $\alpha$ is the angle between the normal vectors of the triangle plane, $\mathbf{\hat n_t}=\frac{\mathbf{PQ}\times\mathbf{PR}}{||\mathbf{PQ}\times\mathbf{PR}||}$, and the projection plane, $\mathbf{\hat n}=\frac{(2,1,1)}{\sqrt{2^2+1^2+1^2}}=\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt 6},\frac{1}{\sqrt 6}\right)$.
You also know that the area of your triangle can be found like
$$A=\frac{1}{2}||\mathbf{PQ}\times\mathbf{PR}||$$
Firstly we'll compute $\mathbf{PQ}$ and $\mathbf{PR}$ and afterwards their cross product:
$$\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&\mathbf{PQ}=(1,2,-1)\\
&\mathbf{PR}=(-1,1,-2)
\end{aligned}\right\}\implies
\mathbf{PQ}\times\mathbf{PR}=
\begin{vmatrix}
\mathbf i & \mathbf j & \mathbf k\\
1 & 2 & -1\\
-1 & 1 & -2
\end{vmatrix}
=(-3,3,3)
$$
This means the area of the triangle is
$$A=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{(-3)^2+3^2+3^2}=\frac{3\sqrt 3}{2}$$
and that the normal to the triangle plane is
$$\mathbf{\hat n_t}=\frac{1}{3\sqrt 3}(-3,3,3)=\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt 3},\frac{1}{\sqrt 3},\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}\right)$$
Finally, the projected area will be
$$A_{\text{proj}}=A\,|\mathbf{\hat n_t\cdot \hat n}|=\frac{3\sqrt 3}{2}\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt 6}\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}(-1,1,1)\cdot(2,1,1)\right|=\frac{\sqrt 3}{2\sqrt 2}\left|-2+1+1\right|=0$$
Which means the area of the projected shadow onto the plane is $0$, namely, only a line will be projected.

Just to clarify, because the normal of the triangle and the normal of the plane are perpendicular the area of the shadow is 0?

Yes, try it yourself in real life on your table or on a notebook for example; you'll see it quickly.
